# Converting ImageMagick code to GD (php)

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, gd

I'd like to convert some PHP code that uses ImageMagick for image processing. I am a total newbie when it comes to using GD but I hope I could get some directions or code suggestions.

The current PHP code can be seen below

```
$rand = rand();
$galleryWidth ='245';
$galleryHeight ='245';

$result = array();

if (isset($_FILES['photoupload']) )
{
    $file = $_FILES['photoupload']['tmp_name'];
    $error = false;
    $size = false;



        list($file_name, $file_type) = split('[.]', $_FILES["photoupload"]["name"]);

       move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photoupload"]["tmp_name"],
      "./photos/org/".$rand.'.'.$file_type);

        list($width,$height)=getimagesize('./photos/org/'. $rand.'.'.$file_type);


        if(($galleryWidth/$width) < ($galleryHeight/$height)){  
        exec("C:/imagemagick/convert ./photos/org/". $rand.".".$file_type."\
            -thumbnail ".round(($width*($galleryWidth/$width)), 0)."x".round(($height*($galleryWidth/$width)), 0)." \
            -quality 90   ./photos/".$_GET['id'].".jpg");
        }
        else{
        exec("C:/imagemagick/convert ./photos/org/". $rand.".".$file_type."\
            -thumbnail ".round(($width*($galleryHeight/$height)), 0)."x".round(($height*($galleryHeight/$height)), 0)." \
            -quality 90   ./photos/".$_GET['id'].".jpg");
        }
        $result['result'] = 'success';
        $result['size'] = "Uploaded an image ({$size['mime']}) with  {$size[0]}px/{$size[1]}px.";

}
?>
```

Thanks for having a look at it!

Comment: There's no universal 'conversion' techniques. Please tell us what are you trying to achieve. It's hard to understand that from your code.

Comment: I'm sorry. Basically it's PHP code for an image uploading form. For the resizing and image quality decreasement to work I will need ImageMagick. "-thumbnail" and "-quality" is not PHP code, it's ImageMagick code. From what I understand GD has similar features but different syntax. The most important thing is to create the thumbnail so that it has correct proportions.

Comment: Any Reason you want to switch back to GD? I would suggest you to switch to [Imagick native php extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php), instead of doing this 'exec()' hackery. you get same features but code will be cross platform & cleaner.

Comment: Unfortunately I have not gotten imagemagick to work. There are a few instructions available on the internet but the imagemagick extension simply don't appear in phpinfo(). I have asked the question previously on Pro Webmasters and marked that question as answered before I even verified it was working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find GDs file format support is a bit limited compared to ImageMagick's, but you're looking for something similar to the following.

```
$inputPath = "./photos/org/{$rand}.{$file_type}";
$outputPath = "./photos/{$imageId}.jpg";

list($old_width, $old_height) = getimagesize($inputPath);

// -- Calculate the new_width and new_height here, however you want to.
$new_width = 250;
$new_height = 250;

// -- Initialise the source image container
if( $file_type == 'png' )
    $src_img = imagecreatefrompng($inputPath);
else if( $file_type == 'jpeg' || $file_type == 'jpg' )
    $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($inputPath);
else
    throw new Exception("Unsupported file format.");

// -- Prepare the new image container
$dst_img = ImageCreateTrueColor($new_width, $new_height);

// -- Resample the "old" image to the "new" image
imagecopyresampled($dst_img, $src_img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $old_width, $old_height); 

// -- Save the new canvas (the 90 represents the quality percentage)
imagejpeg($dst_img, $outputPath, 90); 

// -- Perform cleanup on image containers.
imagedestroy($dst_img); 
imagedestroy($src_img);
```

Comment: Yup. @nctrnl, your ImageMagick calls are just scaling the image to a smaller size, so `imagecopyresampled` is certainly the GD function that springs to mind. If you have more complicated image thumbnailing requirements in the future, maybe look into the [TimThumb PHP library](http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/projects/timthumb/).

Comment: I get this error when trying to upload a jpg file: Warning: getimagesize(./photos/org/1713.) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\employees\upload_foto.php on line 6

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unsupported file format.' in C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\employees\upload_foto.php:18 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\employees\upload_foto.php on line 18

Comment: @nctrnl By the sound of it, because your `$inputPath` isn't set to the path of the image as it comes in.  Correct that, and you should see this error go away.